# image width and height not showing properly in canvas using fabric js

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, fabricjs

I am using Fabricjs to upload images with the current code.

fabric image component not rendered properly as the actual size of the image.

here is my JS code

```
         function addiMage(data) {
            let myImg = './layers/' + data.name + ".png";
            let left = data.bounds.left;
            let top = data.bounds.top
            let scaleX = data.bounds.width;
            let scaleY = data.bounds.height
            let blendOptions = data.blendOptions;
            let index = data.index;
             fabric.Image.fromURL(myImg, function (oImg) {
                    oImg.set({
                        'left': left,
                        'top': top,
                        opacity: blendOptions.opacity,
                
                       
                    });
                   oImg.scaleToHeight(scaleY);
                   oImg.scaleToWidth(scaleX);
                                      
                   canvas.add(oImg);


              
                });
                

           
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

I set the picture size like this, it can be used

```js
fabric.Image.fromURL(myImg, (oImg) => {
      oImg.scale(0.3).set({
        left: setLeft(3),
        top: setTop(6),
        backgroundColor: "orange",
        width: oImg._element.naturalWidth,
        height: oImg._element.naturalHeight,
      });

      canvas.add(oImg);
    });
```